Antenna Radiation and Common mode currents
I've read literate from internet. It said :
here
When does coax radiate?

In order to cause the coax to radiate, the currents must be
unbalanced. This means that the current running on the braid and the
center are not equal and opposite anymore. Their sum is not zero and
the resulting current (called common mode current) radiates. Note that
this can happen also when the system is perfectly matched (i.e. with
VSWR=1).

What is this "Common Mode currents"?
I've learned radio radiation from EMF books it only need currents. (From the Hyat Literatures).

I proving it only transmit 140 meter. I don't know why.

nothing in this universe "transmits 140 m". That's not how electromagnetic waves work.

I prove it only 140 m distances. Yes it in coax. It radiates if current not balances. Regarding to RIGHT HAND RULE.  ITS Biot Savart explained in Hayt. One reduce the other. Because ITS  balance.

What you say makes no sense at all, sorry. The rule of Biot-Savart definitely does not imply that anything could stop transmitting after 140 m. On the contrary, the whole point of Maxwell's Equations is that Waves propagate infinitely. You really seem to be confusing a lot of physical concepts, I'm afraid!

So resultant of H and E is zero. In coax.  I need to radiate signals in Antenna ngab. Not in the coax only. The main lobe should be reach same level power in far end what ever distances.

If the H and E fields are zero in your coax, then you didn't put in energy. There's literally no other way that could be possible.

The answer is literally in the quoted portion of the question post. Voting to close because there's no actual question left to answer.

@webmarc The answer is in the question, which means the questioner did not understand it and needs a bit of elaboration. Frankly, I wonder how many percents of hams understand common mode current correctly. Analog/RF engineers and those working in EMI/noise/interference mitigation fields should know this inside out, but not many people deeply understand this subject.

Desired currents in a coax are equal and opposite.
Common mode currents are going in a common direction.
Since they are not opposite which would cancel, and are going in a common direction, and instead of canceling, they reenforce each other, and cause a signal to escape from the coax.


Whats is this Common Mode currents. Reffers to. Ive learn radio radiation from EMF books it only need currents. (From the Hyat Literatures).

You literally cite the definition of common mode current, I can only repeat:

the current running on the braid and the center are not equal and opposite anymore. Their sum is not zero and the resulting current (called common mode current)

There it says that

Common mode current is the current running on the braid and the center of a coax cable, that doesn't cancel out.


Thanks Marcus Müller. I really appreciates. Your comments.

Common mode current is a circuit concept, not an electromagnetic concept. There is no wave and therefore propagation necessary in generating the common mode current. (The common mode current may be induced by the field generated by the antenna or other pieces of equipment, though.)
In order to create a common mode current from the same transmitter (in a system with one transmitter and one antenna), you must have at least one more connection between the transmitter and the load/antenna. That circuit is often made by the ground, building structure, the AC power line, the ground  connections of various kinds (safety, RF, counterpoise, etc.), or things like the operator's body, earphones, Morse keys, and more problematically, peripherals like audio interface or USB to the computer, control lines, etc. If you remove all of those, and if the antenna exists in free space or on an ideal ground, common mode current does not see any opportunity to arise.

The transmission line's RF current flows on the inner surface of the coax braid due to the proximity effect. On the other hand, the common-mode RF current flows on the outer surface of the braid due to the skin effect. Therefore, the transmission line current and the common mode current do not add or cancel. Consider them flowing through separate sets of conductors.
To mitigate common mode current, we use CMC chokes, which greatly reduces i_{CM} by making the total impedance of that circuit much larger than what it was before. Those are a 1:1 Guanella current transformer with negligible differential mode impedance but very high common-mode or magnetizing impedance (best to maximize the resistive component rather than |Z|) to choke the common mode RF current.
In the case of a dipole or loop, we use a balun to force two arms of the antenna element(s) to have the same RF currents in the opposite direction at the feedpoint. Without a balun, the unbalance can contribute to the common mode current.
One common embodiment of a balun for a dipole or loop antenna is the same 1:1 Guanella current transformer. That is, with those antennas, the balun and the CM chokes serve the same function and benefit, i.e., reduce the common mode current, in addition to keeping an undisturbed radiation pattern.

no, you don't need another connection for common mode current, that's incorrect. On any transmission line, common mode current is simply the net current flowing, after integrating all currents that flow in direction of energy transport. Think about this: you build a vertical quarter wavelenght monopole for, say 30 MHz. But instead of a simple conducting mast, you use a coax cable's outer conductor. At the end of the coax sits a 2.4 GHz antenna, which you feed with the signal transported between inner and outer conductor. Then, from a point of view of that 2.4 GHz antenna, the 30 MHz signal…

is common-mode current. There's no return path for that current – the center conductor is AC coupled with a highpass that effectively blocks anything < 2 GHz.

I need to see a diagram to understand what you are talking about. It sounds like an intentionally created tricky example. @MarcusMüller

OK, let me give you this more direct: Your claim that there needs to be a return path for common mode current is simply wrong; common mode current can be AC. And there's no limit on how long a transmission line can be, so that the common mode current can perfectly well oscillate back and forth on the transmission line itself.

Your second example is even more confusing. @MarcusMüller

Then I can't explain this any better to you, I'm afraid.

"Common mode current" is usually RF or noise. The same thing can happen to DC or low frequency, but in those cases, more direct terminology is used, like "ground loop," "leakage current," or more specific terms because at low frequencies, those things are easier to see.

Yes. And only the "loop" things need a return path. RF common mode current does not have to "have at least one more connection between the transmitter and the load/antenna"; that's simply not the case. Especially when you think about why we're talking about this: The power that causes these common mode currents might simply be emitted as radio waves.

A loop is simply not a requirement for common mode current.

The "connection" is, of course, in the equivalent circuit representation of the antenna/feedline system and the surrounding environment, of course. I'm not talking about literal copper/DC connectivity.

and you'd still be wrong.

I hope you can explain your examples more fully, maybe somewhere else. I know these comment windows are very limiting.

Common mode current is still a current (global current, not local within a piece of conductor like Eddy current), and it needs to satisfy Kirchhoff's law, you know. There needs to be another connection away from the coax for the common mode current to be nonzero. @MarcusMüller

Look. Take 10 m of ladder line, hang it straight veritacally. Attach a matched-impedance termination resistance to its end, and feed it (correctly) with differential current, the current on one conductor opposing the current on the other, and of equal magnitude. Everything cancels, there's no common mode current. Nothing radiates. (Do we agree?) B) Take the same ladder line, but this time, connect both conductors at the bottom. Now, drive that with an AC source whose reference point is the ground below your freshly built monopole construction. Now, there's no differential current, and only

common mode current. There's no return path here – this is just a monopole antenna.

RF currents do not adhere to Kirchhoff, or we could not have antennas at all! You're conflating things. Common mode current is a local description. A ground loop (for example) is something from a fundamentally different category – a "global current" as you would call it.

Your situation (B) transmogrified a transmission line (which transports power) to an antenna (which radiates energy). The equivalent circuit of (B) needs to be that of an antenna. That is, you have a series circuit of radiation impedance, ground resistance, other various ohmic losses and so on. That's a loop created by the ground circuit. However, that antenna current in (B) is usually not called or categorized as a common-mode current. The transmitter is still pushing out a differential mode current.

No, it's you who is making a logical fallacy here. From the point of the transmission line, the current that flows is common mode current in (B). There's really no need to discuss this, that's what the word means. That your model of a transmission line doesn't fit that is not the fault of the word "common mode current", but of your choice of model. And the perspective here has been the transmission line, not the transmitter (remember the question!), so trying to move the question of whether something is common mode current into a different device is an invalid operation.

In your situation B, the ladder line is no longer a transmission line.

By the way, Kirchhoff's law holds perfectly well in RF and electromagnetic discussion. KCL is a fundamental law on the conservation of electric charge; it cannot be violated.

whether you want to call it "transmission line" has absolutely no consequency to the actual line. You can look at any point along the line, and say "on this piece of transmission line there currently is 0 A differntial current and such and such common mode current". And of course I didn't want to make example complicated, but as usual, you get a combination of both in reality.

And you must know a pretty different set of  KCLs than me. KCLs simply assume that the net charge in any component and conductor is constant; that simply doesn't work when the wavelengths of the frequencies you deal with become large compared to the physical realization of circuits. My "linear electric networks" and "theory of transmission line" scriptums back from my studies are sadly in German, but here's at least wikipedia on limitations of KCL. Not the greatest source, I know.

Here's a more authorative source: Agrarwal was MIT professor at that time, and he wrote the standard book on electrical circuit theory. https://web.archive.org/web/20110904144729/http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-002-circuits-and-electronics-spring-2007/video-lectures/6002_l1.pdf As you'll find, a transmission line simply doesn't exist in the lumped element abstraction. Same for antennas: Look at page 17. If the magnetic flux is constant over time outside the antenna, then there's no electromagnetic wave! So, you need to be a lot more careful where to…

… apply the simplifying models of KCL – they typically do not apply to anything transporting RF (instead, you always need to justify how you made something small enough that they actually do apply approximatively. This is the exception, not the usual case!).

It's interesting that you mention my grad school. You are mixing discussions at the different levels of abstraction. Common mode current is a circuit concept, and I have been using an equivalent circuit model (including the parasitic components and all, lumped or distributed). That wikipedia actually describes equivalent circuits and finite element models right there, where KCL applies. In RF equivalent circuits, one piece of the conductor is not considered one node but rather a concatenation of "infinitesimally" small inductors and capacitors. In that sense, KCL still holds perfectly.

In other words, that Wikipedia entry is mischaracterizing the nature of the problem/limitation. It is not a limitation of Kirchhoff's law but rather how "nodes" are assigned/defined inappropriately in their illustration of a coax segment.

no, this is you trying to apply a model outside its domain of validity. The wikipedia article is very explicit about KCL only applying when the lumped circuit abstraction applies.

verbatim quote: "Kirchhoff's circuit laws are the result of the lumped-element model and both depend on the model being applicable to the circuit in question."

The point is that proper equivalent circuit models are lumped element representations where KCL applies. Your quote may be verbatim, but it is being misapplied in your arguments. I see where you are mixing things up. I used to teach circuits, electromagnetics and microwave theory among other things. I'm going to end this exchange now, but all of these comments do not affect or invalidate what I wrote as my answer.

You're – falsely – assuming that from the existence of a model follows the applicability and actual equivalence of that model. That is not the case. But: Greetings to a fellow teacher!

"Common mode current ... needs to satisfy Kirchhoff's law"  I find it useful to apply KCL locally, i.e. zooming in to look at a wire junction or feedpoint. But once you have a quarter wave of wire in the air, it is an antenna. All complex antenna+transmission line+balun+ground problems can be broken up into the basic wiring that obeys KCL and the big simple wire antennas (carrying only common mode currents, or as we normally call them, just Currents).

That's why I kept talking about the equivalent circuit of the system, not the actual copper wiring. @tomnexus

I also mentioned that the coax braid should be viewed as two separate conductors in my answer. There are two currents that do not add or cancel, so the model is actually very simple. @tomnexus

But the main point of the OP is what is common mode current, and there needs to be a current path outside the coax to have common mode current on the coax braid. When you define nodes properly (and again, it can be very simple), both KCL and KVL apply to that model. Note that the antenna itself is replaced with an equivalent model of the antenna in this circuit. @tomnexus

The equivalent circuit and model characterization may vary with dipoles, loops, and whatnot, but the idea is that all those numerous stray RF current paths can be consolidated with an unknown impedance to understand the nature of the common mode current on the coax.

Sure, and I think we agree. Eg in the case of a dipole-fed-with-coax, the big antenna picture shows three wire legs, two quarter wave and one very long. Don't care what's at the end of the coax, its too far away. All carrying current. Now zoom in and there's a tiny voltage source at the end of the coax inside, and three impedances (to "ground"), (and some mutuals). Solve this and you know how much current leaves on each wire. Sum is zero at the feedpoint of course. I'm sorry it's hard to explain in a tweet... I'm just pushing my mental model of unbalanced currents.

In the case of a dipole or loop, we use a balun to force two elements to have the same RF currents in the opposite direction. Without a balun, the unbalance can contribute to the common mode current. We use a common mode choke to greatly reduce i_{CM} by making the total impedance of that circuit much larger than what it was before.
